# Add an external font to Komodo IDE Nightly

Tags: fonts, komodo

I am trying to customize my Komodo IDE Nightly in Windows.

I want to use the font "Source Code Pro" as it is a good one for coding. However it is not in the default list of fonts.

Is it possible to add a font to the list of fonts available in Komodo Nightly? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Komodo uses your system fonts, so to use a new font simply install the font on your system and (re)open the preference dialog.

I use Source Code Pro myself and it works wonderfully :)